# Как сделать анимированную картинку на кнопке с текстом

Tags: java, android, анимация, button

**Задача**

Имеется кнопка с рисунком drawableLeft, при возникновении события нужно начинать проигрывание анимации этой картинки (вращение), потом по другому событию остановить анимацию (окончание передачи данных по сети), был вариант с нажимаемой картинкой, но она не отвечает текущей концепции дизайна

**Проблемы**

- ImageButton не имеет свойства text
- Обычный Button не может воспроизвести анимацию

Comment: Используйте `ImageView` вместе с `TextView`

Comment: я сделал аналогично `ImageView` с `Button`, чтобы избежать создания `drawables` прорисовки состояний кнопки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выход был найден: отрисовка картинки и его анимация поверх кнопки, для этого на форму, где должна быть расположена кнопка с анимированной картинкой, размещается GridLayout, при этом свойства row у объектов button и imageview должны быть одинаковыми, а порядок в xml файле описания должно быть таким, как здесь записано, то есть кнопка затем картинка, иначе картинка перекроется кнопкой.

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:id="@+id/btnSyncro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:text="@string/my_button" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Здесь свойство кнопки `paddingLeft="50dp"` - это место отступа текста, резервируемое для картинки.

Свойства картинки `android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"` и `android:layout_marginTop="6dp"` задают его расположение на кнопке, подбираются опытным путем.

Ниже приведен код для анимации вращения:

```
rot = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
rot.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image));
// Анимация вращения View на 360 градусов
rotate360 = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,   RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotate360.setDuration(1500); // на анимацию отводится 1,5 сек
rotate360.setRepeatCount(-1);// бесконечная анимация
rotate360.setFillAfter(true);
```

Запускаем анимацию, допустим, при клике на кнопку:

```
rotate360.setRepeatCount(-1); // бесконечная анимация
rot.startAnimation(rotate360);
```

Остановка анимации:

```
rot.getAnimation().setRepeatCount(0);
```

Comment: а почему именно GridLayout был выбран для контейнера картинки и кнопки?

Comment: в GridLayout можно указывать свойство row и column, а хотя возможно и в других типах layouts  можно сделать, не проверял, просто GridLayout один из компонентов в моем опыте, в котором я увидел, что можно располагать другие элементы по координатной сетке, в том числе несколько в одной ячейке